# jQuery cannot grab html contenteditable val

Tags: jquery, html

i have a div with `contenteditable="true"` that im using in place of `textarea`
using jQuery, i cant seem to capture its `val()`
[heres my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/jPD7y/2/)

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With it being a `div`, you would grab the `.text()`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPD7y/4/

Answer (score 12):

Some general tips even if you got the answer

.val() = getting value from elements like text,textarea,select,checkbox

.text() = getting text values(**excludes html tags**) from elements like text,textarea,select,checkbox

.html() = getting **html** content from elements like span,div p table..etc..

Examples

```
<input type="text" id="someid" value="1234" />
$('#someid').val(); //1234
<p>bla bla bla<span>hello</span></p>
$('p').text(); //bla bla bla
$('p').html(); //bla bla bla<span>hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not `textarea` but `div` therefore cannot be read with `val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line from....

```
var mypost = $('#myTextArea').val();
```

to

```
var mypost = $('#myTextArea').text();
```